# Fill ListBox using SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, vba, database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am working on ***VBA MS Access Application*** and there needs to populate *ListBox* using by executing stored procedure on ADO Environment. Below is my code... this code is executed when main form loads.

Everything is ok with sql connectivity and on debugging using `Debug.Print`, I can confirm that data is being fetched successfully. But I am getting error on last line.. please need help. Below is my code for filling Listbox....

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Set AdoCn = New ADODB.Connection

Set AdoCmd = New ADODB.Command

AdoCn.Open AdoConnectionString

AdoCmd.ActiveConnection = AdoConnectionString

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

AdoCmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    AdoCmd.CommandText = "TestListReview"
     Set rs = AdoCmd.Execute

     rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    rs.Open cmd, , adOpenForwardOnly, adLockOptimistic, dbSeeChanges
   Set Me.lstReview.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"

    Set Me.mylstbox.Recordset = rs

Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
```

Comment: Show us the error message

Comment: which error are you getting?

Comment: I guess you need to replace `Set cn = Nothing` with `Set AdoCn = Nothing`

Comment: @Horaciux it's Run TIme Error 3705 :Operation is not allowed when the object is open.

Comment: @DeepSharma dude i have mentioned above..

Comment: `rs.Close();AdoCn.Close();` instead of set to nothing. Leave it to garbage collector.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't created a connection named cn.  The connection you created is called AdoCN.  You're trying to close an object that does not exist.  Change the last line to Set AdoCn = nothing as Horaciux suggested.